# Link sheet names with table's contents

Tags: excel, typescript, office-scripts

My question is rather straightforward : I would like to link some sheet names (not all) in my workbook with a table containing a range of dates.

Sheetnames should become sthg like "blablabla" + Table@1.

Here is what I have designed so far but this doesn't quite seem to work unfrotunately.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let i = 0;
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  let dates = workbook.getTable("Months").getColumn(1).getRange().getCell(i, 1); 
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    if (sheet.getName().includes("Capacity split -") && !sheet.getName().includes("Capacity split - Next quarters")){
      let newName = 'Capacity split -' + dates[i];
      console.log(newName);
      sheet.setName(newName)}};

}
```

I add screenshots to explain what I would like exactly.

Tabs' screenshot :

[image: Tabs' screenshot]

Table's data :

[image: Table's data]

The whole idea is to somehow link the first table cell with the second tab etc.

Would you be able to help please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: LesPaul, can you show an example of a workbook with the state before running the script and the state after?

Comment: @JakobNielsen-MSFT unfortunately a moderator deleted my comment. I want to link sheet names with cell values in a table. I believe I'm only short of a for loop on i values, but my javascript knowledge is a bit limited unfortunately.

Comment: +1 to @JakobNielsen-MSFT's comment. Could you edit your original post to include screenshots of the before and after for the desired outcome?
You're also only ever using the value of 0 for `i`. Did you want to increment that in the loop?

Comment: @AlexanderJerabek Indeed I would need to increment my i!

Let me add screenshots to my initial post.

Comment: It looks like you have more entries in your table name than sheets from your screenshot. Is that correct or are there just as many sheets as there are entries in the table? If there are less sheets than entries in the table, the code will just change the sheet names from top to bottom until all sheets that fall into the if statement are renamed. You said in your post that the code doesn't seem to work. What is the code doing? What should it be doing?

Comment: @BrianGonzalez Correct, that's exactly what the code should be doing.

Comment: @LesPaul You can try adding `i += 1;` after `sheet.setName(newName)}};` in your if statement and see if that works.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Console.log outputs => Capacity split -undefined

sheet.setName(newName) outputs =>

Line 9: Worksheet setName: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.

Comment: @LesPaul, unfortunately it is still unclear to me what you want your script to do. I still miss a set of unambiguous before and after screen shots. I am available to jump on a Teams call with you, if you think that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the incredible support provided by Microsoft's Jakob, here is the solution we finally managed to reach :

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let i = 1;
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  //Find and get values from the table containing values
  let dates = workbook.getTable("Months").getColumn(2).getRange().getValues(); 
  //Find and rename the targeted sheets with a temporary name
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    if (sheet.getName().includes("Capacity split -") && !sheet.getName().includes("Capacity split - Next quarters") && !sheet.getName().includes("Capacity split - Dyn overview")) {
      sheet.setName(sheet.getName().replace("Capacity split -", "temp"))}}
  //Rename the targeted sheets with the final names    
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    if (sheet.getName().includes("temp")){
      let newName = 'Capacity split - ' + dates[i][0];
      i+=1;
      sheet.setName(newName)};
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot to all of you for the time and support !

Nicolas.